# Does anyone know where I can find the "Orto" Javascript JVM?

Tags: java, javascript

I've read about "Orto", a Java virtual machine that runs on Javascript, but I can't find the actual code, only a few articles about it - like this one: http://ejohn.org/blog/running-java-in-javascript/

Does anyone know where I can find Orto itself, or something else that can run Java bytecode on Javascript?

Note that the GWT doesn't meet my needs since it is a Java source code to Javascript compiler, not a Java bytecode to Javascript compiler.  My source language is Scala, so GWT won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloads are under "Orto SDK" in the left-hand menu:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080114024903/http://orto.accelart.jp/index.html

However, considering that the Orto project seems to have quietly died, you may be better off looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The homepage of the project Orto was located at http://orto-lang.com and http://orto.accelart.jp/ but seems that are not longer available.

I was able to download Orto SDK using the web archive. Check this:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080114024903/http://orto.accelart.jp/index.html

It's dated January 2008

Comment: For Windows, maybe: http://web.archive.org/web/20070306143200/orto.accelart.jp/archive/orto132ja.exe

Answer (score 0):

This might be the [homepage](http://orto.accelart.jp). But it's all Japanese to me. I clicked a few random links and tried to use Google to translate it, but it didn't work for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: LOL: http://orto.jp/ means: http://translate.google.fr/translate?prev=hp&hl=fr&js=y&u=http%3A%2F%2Forto.jp%2F&sl=ja&tl=en&history_state0= Hair. NET provides hair restoration hair as well as useful information such as your eating good food and hair basics, supplements and other items, links. Not sure if that is what you are looking for;)

Comment: Welcome to the 10K world, by the way ;)

Comment: @VonC, yes that was not the link I meant to post. I've updated it, but it seems to be down

Comment: I know: I was checking both orto.accelart.jp and orto.jp, but both went down in 2008. Are you thinking what I am thinking? Internet ARCHIVE! Go...

Comment: http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20080114024903%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Forto.accelart.jp%2Findex.html

Comment: the cache is blocked for me at work, it is somewhat frustrating