# How do I use packages I created in java in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I've got a package login that has a few classes inside of it...I thought my code would look like this:

```
importPackage(login);
var password = document.form1.pword.value;
var hash = JPP7.toHash(password);
```

where JPP7 is the class of mine that does the hashing? I am using a colleagues javascript code, but I know next to nothing about javascript. Am I going to have to give an absolute path to the package folder?

Comment: Umm, you can't (easily) use Java code in Javascript. Despite the similarity in their names, they are very different and are incompatible with each other.

Comment: If you willing to write a converter from `Java` to `JavaScript`, that would be very nice!

Comment: but really, without sarcasm... you can not use `java` packages in `javascript`

Comment: Why the down vote on this question? A lack of knowledge doesn't constitute a detrimental question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: thats so awkward. I totally thought this was a thing. Well, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*(Converted from my comment above)*</sup>

**You cannot** (at least not easily nor out-of-the-box) use Java code in Javascript. Despite the similarity in their names, they are very different and are incompatible with each other. See also [What's the difference between Javascript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java).

There was once an [implementation of the JVM in Javascript](http://ejohn.org/blog/running-java-in-javascript/), but it [seems to now be dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444681/does-anyone-know-where-i-can-find-the-orto-javascript-jvm). I wouldn't have recommended using it in any sort of production code anyway.

Comment: @Raynos Well perhaps you should provide a link to it?