# JavaScript jvm implementation

Tags: java, javascript, browser, compiler-construction

Is there any **JavaScript jvm implementations**?  
If no, can you give me some reasons why it hasn't realized already? (not possible probably?) I'm trying to understand what is absent to create one?

Reason why i'm asking is that i want to create web browser ide with compile functionality without even having jdk or jre installed on the computer(just in browser).

Comment: I have little experience in Java, but still.. Think about it, your JVM wont be able to access disk, OS, or make random network connections, because of the various limitations the browser puts.. HTH

Comment: *"web browser ide with compile functionality"* It would pay to mention the goal 1st up in future, to clear some confusion. ;)

Comment: It would be infinitely easier to just send the Java-code to the server and compile it there.

Comment: @pap  Preventing Denial of Service attacks on the server for code compilation cannot be 'infinitely easier'.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - let's make a race. You start implementing a JVM in JavaScript and I'll get cracking on DOS-proofing a low-profile website. Let's see who finishes first ;)

Comment: Anyone that would run Java Applets (ie. java for web browsers)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how mature [jsJVM](https://github.com/Jivings/jsJVM) is but looks like something which you would be interested in. As the page says, it's JVM written in Javascript.

Comment: jsJVM looks to be completely abandoned. Doppio seems to be the most relevant now, but is kind of broken from time to time.

Answer (score 18):

Most current one seems to be **[Doppio](http://plasma-umass.github.io/doppio-demo/)**

Comment: Has this JVM implementation a GUI API?

Answer (score 7):

You may have a look at the **bck2brwsr** (aka java.net HTML)

- it is a VM that transforms java byte code into JavaScript (Bck2Brwsr Virtual Machine)
- provides a Java based wrapper to HTML (HTML via Java APIs)

The scope of the project is **not** to execute **any** existing java library. (see http://wiki.apidesign.org/wiki/Bck2Brwsr)

There are two nice examples on the web:

- a calculator, that gives good technical insight (http://xelfi.cz/bck2brwsr/)
- a nice space invader demo as a proof of concept (JAYDAY 2013 java summit page)

To **get started** with a **working example** (needs Maven and JDK7):

Step 1: load archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apidesign.bck2brwsr \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=bck2brwsr-archetype-html-sample -DarchetypeVersion=0.7.2 \
 -DarchetypeRepository=https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/
```

Step 2: build HTML page and dependencies and pack as ZIP file

```
mvn install
# produces bck-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bck2brwsr.zip
```

Step 3: unpack ZIP

```
cd target; unzip bck-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bck2brwsr.zip
  creating: public_html/
  creating: public_html/lib/
  extracting: public_html/lib/emul-0.7.2-rt.jar  
  extracting: public_html/lib/javaquery.api-0.7.2.jar  
  inflating: public_html/bck2brwsr.js  
  extracting: public_html/bck-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  
  inflating: public_html/index.html
```

Step 4: open **index.html** with your browser

Answer (score 3):

1. [+script](http://www.keithschwarz.com/+script/) seems to be interesting, too and the author also works on an web based IDE.
2. [BicaVM](http://www.surf-the-edge.com/2011/11/15/bicavm-jvm-in-javascript-why/) may be another option.
3. The [Orto](https://github.com/robterrell/orto) project may be dead.

   - [Does anyone know where I can find the "Orto" Javascript JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444681/does-anyone-know-where-i-can-find-the-orto-javascript-jvm)
   - http://ejohn.org/blog/running-java-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but for future inquirers:  There is a new Java JVM implementation for JavaScript that has been released since this question was first asked.  It claims to implement a JVM even without Java installed.

https://www.javapoly.com/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Is that better?  And can someone explain why my answer was downvoted and deleted, whereas the Doppio answer above was upvoted 12 times and provided no more useful information than my answer?

Comment: Has this JVM implementation a GUI API?

Comment: Unfortunately looks dead

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems of compiling Java using JavaScript is that the compiler typically needs to know the existence (or not) of the methods and attributes of a target Java minimum version.  To even know that information, you would need to store properties, or variables that describe the public members of every single of class of the target J2SE.  That represents a *very big* chunk of information.

Comment: Can't you put that staff in coockie or html5 Local Storage ?

Comment: I doubt the '5 meg' of expected space in local storage would be enough to hold textual representations of those public and (I forgot) protected members of non-final classes for a JRE of the vintage of 1.6 or 1.7.  Maybe 1.1 & 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

There is an JVM written in Java which has an JavaScript Bytecode Interpreter:
https://gitlab.com/neoexpert/jvm

It can also compile Bytecode directly to JavaScript to improve performance.